# how to compare the similarity of two 2D bezier curves

Tags: bezier

I am not familiar with bezier curves, but I need to compare two bezier curves for my project. A quick idea come up in my mind is to sample the two curves and then compare the sampled polylines using something like laplacian coordinates. This way I am comparing the points on the curve, which makes sense. But then I need to worry about the sampling rate. Another idea is to compare the control points of the bezier curves, however I am not sure if it makes sense to do so. Does anyone have experience on doing comparison between bezier curves?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please define comparison in a more formal way. Are you interested in a shape only, or scaling and translation of curves matters as well? Controls points define curve in an exact way, so average distance between control point sets gives you a robust measure of difference between curves.

Comment: so basically what I need to achieve is to let the control points move slightly to satisfy some constraints but also preserve the overall shape in a certain degree. what I did was:
say we have a curve with 4 points, p1,p2,p3,p4, and the changed result is p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_.
basically I do minimization of |(p1-p2) - (p1_-p2_)|^2 + |(p3-p2) -(p3_-p2_)|^2...

Comment: In your case you are trying to keep segment vectors changes minimal, but it would be more natural to keep point changes minimal: |p1-p1_|^2 + |p2-p2_|^2 + |p3-p3_|^2 + |p4-p4_|^2 or another option is to keep length of p1p2p3p4 polygonal line (|p2-p1| - |p2_-p1_|)^2 + (|p3-p2| - |p3_-p2_|)^2 + (|p4-p3| - |p4_-p3_|)^2 minimal, as this one will result in minimization of changes in Bezier curve length.